# SQL column select alias without subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to select a column alias without using subqueries in sql 2008?

***** what I'd like to do: ******

```
Select col1*col2 as NewColumn, NewColumn*col3 from table
```

When I try this though I get the error:

> Invalid column name 'NewColumn'

****what I am doing now instead *****

```
Select Newcolumn*col3 from (Select col1*col2, col3 from mytable) Q1
```

I'd like to avoid subquery where possible as I'm joining many tables and want to make the query more readable.

Perhaps there is an even better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a subquery or a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery or CTE . . . Or, if you really want, `outer apply`:

```
select x.NewColumn, x.NewColumn * col3
from . . . cross apply
     (select col1*col2 as NewColumn) x;
```

Comment: @Rdisnic . . . Your request is to avoid subqueries to keep the query readable.  Adding one more expression in the `FROM` clause is not the same as an additional level of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making this complicated when you can easily do this,

Try this,

```
Select col1*col2 as NewColumn, col1*col2*col3 as NewColumn2 from table
```

Hope this will help.